# No route to host before ping

Tags: networking

I have a really strange problem with a netbook running Lubuntu and no Ipv6 configured, since I want to use only Ipv4.

When I try to ping or connect to the netbook with any protocol with my laptop (Ubuntu 13.04 also with no Ipv6) in any way, I get the error:

> ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: No route to host

I don't have this problem while connecting from my laptop to any other computer.

Now the strange thing. If I ping my laptop from the netbook, everything gets OK and I can connect from there on without any problems. If I restart the laptop, the problem appears again.

Does anybody have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: have you tried `traceroute` command to see where's the problem happening along the way ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the output of "route" command over here. Seems your machine is missing the default gateway, and that needs to be added. if in the output of route command you donot see a default gateway added, you should add it appropriately using `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.254` or add it to the interface file by adding this line `gateway 192.168.1.254` . then, do a networking restart.

P.S. : Replace 192.168.1.254 with the appropriate IP of the default gateway of your network. You can view default gateway of you network from the other machine.

Comment: Route from my laptop:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

Comment: Route from my netbook:

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0